# Question about workflow

Tags: workflow, baking

I have been fiddling around with blender on and off for a while now (I'm still a complete noob.)

My question is about workflow, more specifically what should be done in which order. Obviously you have to model your object first then texture it. But what about stuff like baking? Do I need to do seperate bakes for each thing? Like AO, high poly mesh bake onto low poly mesh? Any help would be appreciated I find most tutorials have little to no explanation about why you are doing things in a certain order and the order is different between tutorials.

Thanks in advance, everyone.

Comment: I would say that it is based on experiences. The workflow may be similar in overall structure. But in those detail, depend on artist behavior. Some might need a cup of coffee for doing something tiring, *e.g. weight painting*. So he might do other thing first in order to adjust when to do the specified job. And of course, based on what is the goal of your work, it will lead to different workflow.